# Linq : filter duplicated line without taking account a column

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to remove from a datatable the duplicated lines, but without taking into account a column into the duplication filter.

Example :

```
| Name | Region |
| Toto |   5    |
| Toto |   2    |
| Toto |   1    |
| Gege |   2    |
```

What I'm searching for if to filter it as the following

```
| Name | Region |
| Toto |   5    |
| Gege |   2    |
```

Thank for your help.

Comment: have you tried distinct on the name?

Comment: @Kram distinct only works on the query as a whole.

Comment: var result = query.GroupBy(x => x.Name)
                  .Select(group => group.First());

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/491832/3419534

Comment: Can i suggest you a integration of distinct called DistinctBy? https://www.nuget.org/packages/MoreLinq.Source.MoreEnumerable.DistinctBy/

Comment: you can use MoreLinq like so: var result = query.AsEnumerable()
                  .DistinctBy(x => x.Name);

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var filteredData = data.GroupBy( d=> d.Name).SelectMany(grouping => grouping.First());
```

Depending upon LinqProvider for the database ([IQueryable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.iqueryable(v=vs.110).aspx) implementation), The query may run on database, or on client side( if so, there will be memory/network bandwidth issues).

In some case, not all Linq constructs are supported.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`datatable.GroupBy(x => x.Name);`

you need to add a using for the `System.Linq` namespace.